# Insertar pagina HTML en correo via php

Tags: php, html

Buenas, tengo una duda. Estoy tratando de enviar una página en html via mail,
al ejecutar una funcion en php, en vez de colocar directamente el html dentro de la función.

Por ver un ejemplo claro de lo que necesito seria algo asi:
Boton asignado a la funcion de enviar mail
que el cuerpo de ese mail tenga el contenido, incluido el css, de una pagina html.

Simplemente quiero quitar el html del mensaje y poner una especie de referencia a una web, coger de esta su contenido y ponerlo en el correo

```html
$para  = 'mail@servidormail.com';
 
// Asunto
$titulo = 'NUEVO PEDIDO';
 
// Cuerpo o mensaje
$mensaje = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hay un nuevo pedido</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Hay un nuevo pedido</h2>
 <a href="https://www.miweb.com/pedidos/last.php">CLICK AQUI</a>
</body>
</html>
';
 
$cabeceras  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
 

$cabeceras .= 'From: Recordatorio <mail@servidormail.com>' . "\r\n";

mail($para, $titulo, $mensaje, $cabeceras);
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Creo que necesitas aclarar esto un poco: *Simplemente quiero quitar el html del mensaje y poner una especie de referencia a una web, coger de esta su contenido y ponerlo en el correo*.  ¿Lo que quieres es traer todo el contenido de esa URL al cuerpo del mensaje? ¿Es una URL perteneciente a tu dominio o puede ser de otro dominio externo?

Comment: exacto, quiero traer el contenido de una url al cuerpo del mensaje, y esa url pertenece a mi dominio

Comment: Si es en el mismo dominio perfecto. Yo no lo haría por medio de una URL... no tiene sentido. Simplemente incluiría el archivo donde lo necesite: `include('ruta/last.php');`, por supuesto, el archivo tendría todo el contenido que tú necesitas para enviar. **[Aquí tienes la documentación sobre `include`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.include.php)**. Y tendrías que indicar a la función `mail` que envíe el contenido en HTML. Si tienes problema de parte de la función `mail` puedes usar la librería PHPMailer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que el contenido que quieres incluir se encuentra en el mismo dominio, lo mejor sería utilizar la función [`include()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.include.php) de PHP, que existe para esos fines. Luego, con [`ob_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.ob-get-contents.php) podrás guardar el contenido del archivo incluido en una variable para enviarla en el email.

El código sería así:

### Script del envío del email

```
$para  = 'mail@servidormail.com';

// Asunto
$titulo = 'NUEVO PEDIDO';

// Cuerpo o mensaje

ob_start();
 /*
    *Si last.php y el script de email no están en el mismo directorio
    *deberás indicar en el include la ruta correcta de last.php
 */
include "last.php";
$mensaje = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$cabeceras  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";   
$cabeceras .= 'From: Recordatorio <mail@servidormail.com>' . "\r\n";    
$bolEnviar=mail($para, $titulo, $mensaje, $cabeceras);

if($bolEnviar){

    echo "Mensaje enviado exitosamente";

}else{

    echo "Hubo un error ".error_get_last()['message'];
}
```

### `last.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <title>Hay un nuevo pedido</title>  
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
      <h2>Hay un nuevo pedido</h2>
    <?php

    /*Código PHP del archivo*/

    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: me ha servido a la perfección, gracias!  una consulta rápida, hay alguna alternativa al padding para mail? es que estoy viendo que no funciona

Comment: ¿Al `padding`... te refieres a código CSS? La verdad no sé. ¿Se muestra bien si lo visualizas como documento HTML?

Comment: si, como documento html se ve correctamente, al mandarlo en email ya no, habia leido en internet que era un dolor de cabeza poner padding en un email

Comment: @Tefef en efecto, parece que hay algunos problemas con `padding`, en algunos clientes  de correo como Outlook. Así rápido, la alternativa que se me ocurre es usar `&nbsp;` en su lugar. Es un poco feo pero bueno. Para mejorar el código, lo puedes poner en una variable, por ejemplo, un tabulador de 5: `$tab5="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";`, así, en vez de llenar el código de eso horrible, usas `$tab5`.