# envio de mail con php

Tags: php, mail

buenos dias.
Tengo un archivo.php que envía mail con la función mail() de PHP
Esto funciona bien cuando envío correos a otros mails que no sean mi servidor
test@otroservidor.cl
test@otroservidor2.cl
etc

A todos estos les llega perfecto pero a los correos de @miservidor.cl no llegan.

A todo esto los mx de mi hosting los tengo con google no se si tengo que configurar algo en los mx o es algo del servidor para poder recibirlos

**De ante mano muchas gracias**

Comment: ¿Revisaste la carpeta spam o correo no deseado? ¿Tienes filtros configurados en tu correo de servidor que puedan estar redirigiendo a otra parte o bloqueando?

Comment: Revise spam y filtros y no existe nada

Comment: Trata de verificar si `mail` está siendo erróneo y capturar el error que emite, [aquí hay un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/131738/29967). Fíjate sólo en la parte de `mail`, no hagas caso a lo que habla de `ob_` pues es otro contexto.

Comment: Sería hacer algo parecido a esto: `$bolEnviar=mail($para, $titulo, $mensaje, $cabeceras);
if($bolEnviar){
    echo "Mensaje enviado exitosamente";
}else{
    echo "Hubo un error ".error_get_last()['message'];
}` cambiando las variables por tus datos reales.

Comment: Uso esa función y el envío es exitoso, el problema es que el mail llega a otros servidores pero no llega al mio

Comment: ¿Y si envías un correo por ejemplo desde Gmail sí llega? Es raro que lo bloquee, más aún si se manda desde el mismo servidor ¿no?

Comment: si entro a mi correo puedo enviar y recibir normalmente. el único problema es que no recibe los email desde el mismo servidor. No se si sera por los mx (5 creados apuntando a google) o alguna otra configuración

Comment: Pero, ¿por qué tienes los MX apuntando a Google? ¿Usas G Suite?

Comment: Si, uso G Suite para enviar y recibir correos. pero también tengo un formulario en la web donde quiero enviarme correos con la función mail

Comment: Revisa las recomendaciones de Google según tu hosting, [aquí tienes que seleccionar](https://support.google.com/a/topic/1611273) qué hosting aloja tu sitio para verificar. También puedes consultar [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24644450/5587982) con varias indicaciones sobre depuraciones que podrías hacer.

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo resolvi agregando esto a mi correo: .test-google-a.com
Ejemplo: micorreo@miservidor.cl.test-google-a.com